# Can't get Paliarush Magento 2 Vagrant for developers to switch to EE mode

Tags: magento2.2, vagrant, magento-enterprise-2, cloud

Please see my [issue report on github](https://github.com/paliarush/magento2-vagrant-for-developers/issues/162) for extreme details.